# Neder of 11 year old girl

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, minor-katan-child, nedarim-shevuot

An 11 year old girl made a neder that if she finds a certain object that she had lost then she'll give to tzedeka 20 agarot (which is today around 5 cents) every week (for the rest of her life.)

Does the neder take affect? Could her Father be "mafir" her neder?

(As a side note I had a doubt also over here if a neder can take affect on something less than a prutah however it seems to be that 5 cents is more than a prutah so that woudln't be part of the question -- a prutah is around 2 cents. I'm mentioning this just in case someone might point out this fact and that I don't think it applies over here.)

Comment: Where do you get your calculation for a Perutah, and if it isn't relevant why are mentioning it in the question?

Comment: Also, is this Halachah LeMa'aseh? And what makes this a unique case?

Comment: @SethJ I put all the information I had, plus some other points that if I would have left them out I'm sure someone would have said something!

Comment: @SethJ Unique or not, doesn't matter, I used this example to express the question (was once halacha l'maseh, don't know what was originally paskened.)

Comment: @SethJ A prutah is 1/40 gram of silver. $0.02 is pretty accurate today.

Comment: There are different types of prutah. Another reckoning is that a prutah is the smallest coin with which one can buy an individual item as an item and not by weight. A dime is the lowest that I've heard, but it could potentially be reduced to a nickel.

Comment: The Israeli economy could undergo a massive deflation and 20 agarot may come to be worth more than a peruta.

Answer (score 1):

Which *Neder* (vow/oath) can the father nullify?
The vows that cause her physical pain (*inui nefesh*), and those that affect between him and her (*beino levainah*)rosh, ritva, Ran, nimmukei yosef and tosfos)
Alternatively Any neder whatsoever (Rambam hilchos Nedarim 12,1 see kesef mishna there).

Ussually the father owns the money (her work payment and findings belong to her father Nidda 47a) , this is between him and her since he would pay up in order for her to fulfil her *neder* as she doesn't own any money yet. So as long as he is *mefer* (nullifies) ביום שמעו - on the day he hears the *neder*  (numbers 30,6) her *neder* is nulified according to everyone.

If she has enough money from her own pocket to give to charity e.g she inherited from her deceased divorced mother or received a present on condition her father cannot benefit, then this is nothing to do with her father,only the Rambam would allow to *Mefer* her *Neder*.

What happens when she goes out of her fathers reshus (Domain) e.g marriage/full maturity?

According to Ran, Rosh, tosfos and nimukei yosef ritva then the *neder* comes back on to her and she has to now fulfill it . this is because SA YD, 234,55:  ודברים שבינו לבינה אין ההתרה אלא לעצמו כל זמן שיש לו בו תועלת דהיינו כל זמן שהיא תחתיו - Matters between her and him there is nullification of the vow only when he has a reason i.e it affects him. That is only whilst she is in his domain.

However according to the Rambam the vow is completely nullified for ever as the father has complete power over whatever neder she says even if it doesn't affect him whatsoever.